# one signal API: How to get number recipients with tags filter

Tags: onesignal

I need to get number recipients with some applied tags filter per App (campaign) via API before sending notification, Is It possible ? Because when set some tags into filter and make request for sending notification then It sends and returns 
`[{"id":"xxxxxxxx-1d54-476e-b8d4-xxxxxxxx","recipients":5,"name":"test - campaign"}]` where I see number recipients.

I need to get this number without sending, did Someone do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with OneSignal's API at this time.